# How to fold multiple single line comments in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, comments

As per the solution from previous posts, I tried to **fold all blocked comments** from the command palette but nothing happens. I have tried a lot of extensions/plugins but still, I can't fold them. Any solution to this? I have to close everything manually. However, in the IDE I can fold multiple single-line comments by hitting the down arrow on the left. Is there any shortcut or particular plugin/ extension for this ?
Am I commenting in the wrong way?[image: comments]

Answer (score 0):

You have used `//` which is a single line comment
Use `/*...your code ...*/` for block comments

Shortcut for block comment is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in VS Code

Comment: They are all single line comments,

Comment: @pannam Yes, block comments can be folded. Not single line comments.

Comment: @RishabhKumarSingh yes it can be! there is an option within the Ide itself towards the left with a downward arrow to fold it.

Comment: @pannam By your comment it seems like you already know the solution.

Comment: @pannam I am asserting that block comments can be folded but not single line comments. Your code has single line comments. They are not foldable.

Comment: @JoãoSoares  and @Rishab Kumar Singh    Apologies if my question wasn't clear, I have uploaded gifs to show what I mean. I have numerous `// single line comments` that need to be closed, is there a way to do it other than manually? I don't want to use `/*..... */` as they are just used as notes at different times

Comment: @pannam Got it. I have added an answer. Please try that. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you for helping out but I can't get it to work. could you please confirm it's worked for you on the comments I posted. If yes, I will reset my IDE then give it another go.?